# AVD not working after edit api level of avd

Tags: android

I edit avd from from API Level-14 to google API's(Google Inc.)-API Level-8... after this my edited avd not working.. its show only black screen after some loading..like crash over some times....whats the reason ... help... thanks

```
10-11 14:55:02.548: W/PackageParser(397): /data/app/SoftKeyboard.apk (at Binary XML file line #0): Requires newer sdk version #14 (current version is #8)
10-11 14:55:02.548: W/PackageParser(397): /data/app/GestureBuilder.apk (at Binary XML file line #23): Requires newer sdk version #14 (current version is #8)
10-11 14:55:02.568: I/PackageManager(397): /data/app/CubeLiveWallpapers.apk changed;       collecting certs
10-11 14:55:02.658: I/PackageManager(397): /data/app/CubeLiveWallpapers.apk changed; unpacking
10-11 14:55:02.678: W/PackageParser(397): /data/app/WidgetPreview.apk (at Binary XML file line #23): Requires newer sdk version #14 (current version is #8)
10-11 14:55:02.888: D/dalvikvm(397): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7086 objects / 373856 bytes in 99ms
10-11 14:55:03.118: W/PackageParser(397): No actions in intent filter at /data/app/ApiDemos.apk Binary XML file line #2584
10-11 14:55:03.118: W/PackageParser(397): No actions in intent filter at /data/app/ApiDemos.apk Binary XML file line #2590
10-11 14:55:03.138: I/PackageManager(397): /data/app/ApiDemos.apk changed; collecting certs
10-11 14:55:03.318: D/dalvikvm(397): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6353 objects / 365648 bytes in 86ms
10-11 14:55:03.618: D/dalvikvm(397): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1876 objects / 315992 bytes in     80ms
10-11 14:55:04.198: D/dalvikvm(397): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3409 objects / 234344 bytes in 84ms
```

Comment: Just create another AVD!

Comment: try to create new avd in api level-14!

Comment: make sure launch from snapshot option is unchecked after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Tick the checkbox "Wipe user data" during AVD launch or simply create new AVD.

Comment: yes its working.....simply i try to understand why this happens? i know that after create new avd its work but why not after avd?   thank you very much...

Comment: I suppose this is because persisted device image contains installed APK's which were compiled for higher API level (14), therefore when you change your API level (to 8) they become incompatible with it